# Sandbox - payment status "complete" even if buyer account has zero balance

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am working on Paypal IPN. My code works fine.
I am getting "complete" status even if my buyer account has no balance it his account?

why this is the case?

Is this the real time scenario when it goes on live paypal???

Comment: In sandbox account you need not to worry......when live paypal that won't happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry, the sandbox always has money so it can show you transaction return codes. It also doesn't go hard into credit card verifications if you have that too.

I was scared that might happen when I did my first payment system but then I thought even if it happens, they'll lose the money not me.